# Http TLS handshake error when using InfluxDb and Telegraf for Grafana

Tags: openssl, grafana, influxdb, telegraf, insomnia

I generated certificate and key (`.crt` and `.key`) files with the OpenSSL tool, and set the generated file paths to these files in the `influxdb.conf` file.

When I run my Telegraf service, the Influxd logs:

```
http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:63020: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

I then opened my `telegraf.conf` and set URLs to localhost, and reinstalled the service with that config file.

I then run my Influx demon with the correct config file (`influxdb.conf`) and connect it to Influxdb with `influx.exe` without a problem. I can query my data normally, but if I try to do a request from Insomnia or Postman the Influxd logs:

```
http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:63175: local error: tls: bad record MAC
```